# Set property on object while iterating

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am making a SPA with Laravel(backend) and Vue.js. I have the following arrays:

accessArray:

```
["BIU","CEO","Finance","HRD","Group"]
```

access:

```
["BIU","Group"]
```

I want to compare the `access` array to the `accessArray` array and if there is a match to change the record (in the `accessArray`) and add a `true` value otherwise add a `false` value.  I am doing this inside a Vue method.

... so far I got this:

```
var foo = ["BIU","CEO","Finance","HRD","Group"];
var bar = ["BIU","Group"];

$.each(bar, function (key, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value, foo) != -1) {
        var position = $.inArray(value, foo);
        console.log(value + ' is in the array.  In position ' + position);
        foo[position] = {name: value, checked: true};
    }
});
```

Which outputs this to the console:

```
BIU is in the array.  In position 0
Group is in the array.  In position 4
```

And this in Vue:

```
[
{"name":"BIU","checked":true},
"CEO",
"Finance",
"HRD",
{"name":"Group","checked":true}
]
```

**The output I would like to achieve is the following:**

```
[
{"name":"BIU","checked":true},
{"name":"CEO","checked":false},
{"name":"Finance","checked":false},
{"name":"HRD","checked":false},
{"name":"Group","checked":true}
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have looked at many similar problems on SO but cant seem to find anything along these lines.  I have also tried to add an else statement on the end but I (think) I'm converting it to an object so that doesn't seem to work.

Edit:

The data in foo comes from a Laravel config setting so is somewhat dynamic

The data in bar is JSON received from the Laravel ORM (its json stored in a text field)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option with vanilla javascript:

```js
var foo = ["BIU","CEO","Finance","HRD","Group"];
var bar = ["BIU","Group"];

var result = foo.map(name => {
    var checked = bar.indexOf(name) !== -1
    return { name, checked }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why does `return { name, checked }` results in an entry with key and value pair? Can you hint to the documentation related to this?

Comment: @BennettDams it's an ES6 shorthand with [object initialisation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) - it's to reduce the repetition when having to write something like `{id: id, name: name}` and similar.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the array and construct a new one, by checking if values are present in the other one through [Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const accessArray = ["BIU","CEO","Finance","HRD","Group"];
const access = [ "BIU", "Group" ];

const result = accessArray.map( a => ({ name: a, checked: access.includes(a)}) ) ;

console.log(result);
```

A note: when using an arrow function and you want to return an object, you need to surround the object literal in `()` otherwise it would be interpreted as a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and inside the reduce call back check if the item is present in both   `accessArray`  & `access` . Create an object and the item present in both array set the value of `checked` to true or false

```js
let arr1 = ["BIU", "CEO", "Finance", "HRD", "Group"]
let arr2 = ["BIU", "Group"];

let k = arr1.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let obj = {}
  if (arr2.includes(curr)) {
    obj.name = curr;
    obj.checked = true
  } else {
    obj.name = curr;
    obj.checked = false
  }
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;


}, []);

console.log(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result use below option
1. Loop foo array
2.Remove initial if condition -  "if ($.inArray(value, foo) != -1)" to loop through all
3.  Do conditional check for checked - checked: $.inArray(value, bar) !== -1 ? true : false

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GXbQOw?editors=1011

```js
  var foo = ["BIU","CEO","Finance","HRD","Group"];
    var bar = ["BIU","Group"];
    
    $.each(foo, function (key, value) {
        foo[key] = {name: value, checked: $.inArray(value, bar) !== -1 ? true : false};
    });
    
    console.log(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Option 2**:
Without using jquery and using simple forEach to loop through foo

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YOoaNb

```js
      var foo = ["BIU","CEO","Finance","HRD","Group"];
      var bar = ["BIU","Group"];

foo.forEach((v,i) => foo[i] = {name: v , checked : bar.includes(v)})
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: There is really no need for jQuery. Using it for such simple task is an overkill. You can use vanilla JS function `Array.forEach`.

Comment: yes @KonradKalemba, just correcting the logic which SO has used , simple map or forEach works in this case.  SO can use this if jquery is used at other places in his application and jquery is also tagged in this question :)

Comment: @KonradKalemba, added option 2 using forEach for loop and without using jquery

Comment: Ahh, my bad. I didn't see `jQuery` tag.